# Does Apache Camel supports activemq wildcard consumers?

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, wildcard, consumer

I need a way to consume messages from multiple activemq jms queues.

As per activemq documentation, it supports [wildcard consumers](http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html)

I am using camel as a messaging bus.Is it possible to look at below named queues

```
aaa.processQueue
bbb.processQueue
ccc.processQueue
```

By configuring camel route to look at `activemq:*.processQueue`  endpoint?

Also let me know, if there is more cleaner alternative for this.

Comment: I don't know if wild cards work, but if they don't you could define multiple routes each using the same processor to read from different queues. Though that does depend on you knowing the name and number of queues before hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It should be doable as Camel is using the OpenWire/JMS client.

Your options are:

1. `from("activemq:*.processQueue")`
2. `from("activemq:aaa.processQueue,bbb.processQueue,ccc.processQueue")`
3. Multiple routes with a sub route for logic:

   ```
   from("activemq:aaa.processQueue").to("direct:doProcess");
   from("activemq:bbb.processQueue").to("direct:doProcess");
   from("activemq:ccc.processQueue").to("direct:doProcess");

   from("direct:doProcess").whatever..
   ```

   This way, you can easily turn on/off routes as well as assigning more consumers to one, given you     need to have more priority on `aaa.processQueue` messages than the rest.

Comment: If some one sends message to aaa.processQueue or bbb.processQueue how do we distinguish whether the message was being sent to aaa.processQueue or bbb.processQueue?

Comment: Then why would you do wildcard consumer if you need to separate them?

Comment: In my application, I am using wildcard like this:   *.processQueue; but while sending a message I will be sending to {uniqueId}.processQueue. I need to get that uniqueId in bean or processors; Can I do that?

Comment: It's essentially another question, but you can always look at the `JMSDestination` property of the message..

Comment: There is example on their github:

Answer (score 0):

They have an example on their github of a routebuilder using wildcards:

```
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            // use wildcard to consume from all sports
            from("activemq:queue:sport.>")
                .to("log:received?showHeaders=true")
                .choice()
                    // the JMSDestination contains from which queue the message was consumed from
                    .when(header("JMSDestination").isEqualTo("queue://sport.pl.chelsea"))
                        .to("mock:chelsea")
                    // we can use a reg exp to match any message from 1st division
                    .when(header("JMSDestination").regex("queue://sport.1st.*"))
                        .to("mock:1st")
                    .otherwise()
                        .to("mock:other")
                .end();
        }
    };
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jms/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/jms/activemq/ActiveMQConsumeWildcardQueuesTest.java